# Exporting to Quickbooks?

Tags: quickbooks

I have an Access 2000 program handling the receiving of goods in the company. 
I need to Export Inventory Items and Quantities to Quickbook (enterprise 2007?). I have a good handle on the Access program, but know nothing about quickbooks.
Can this be done? What would I need for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [QuickBooks SDK](http://developer.intuit.com/technical_resources/default.aspx?id=1490). If you want something simpler to work with, [QODBC](http://www.qodbc.com/qodbc.htm) (with the write capabilities), while not free, will probably be simpler to work with for Access.

Answer (score 5):

Look into the [QuickBooks SDK](http://developer.intuit.com/), a free download from Intuit. It provides a COM object interface or XML interface to all of the QuickBooks data. Additionally, if you need to do this over a WAN, you can use the [QuickBooks Web Connector](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/) to talk to QuickBooks asynchronously over a WAN.

QuickBooks integration is **not** a trivial thing to accomplish. There are many gotchas. Your best friend will be the [Intuit Developer Network forums](https://idnforums.intuit.com/).

You **do not** want to use QIF, QFX, or IIF exports. They are deprecated formats which can cause data corruption. Additional information about various methods of integrating with QuickBooks can be found on this [integration wiki page](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_methods) and on this [QuickBooks integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks).

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend here.  Quickbooks has some primitive import capabilities, but there are a number of small products that do what you need.  [This guy](http://www.bigredconsulting.com/) seems to have some pretty good stuff.  Essentially there are a couple of different text formats (QIF and OFX if memory serves) that are used for Quickbooks import, the problem with them is they don't do much error checking.  There is also a Quickbooks SDK which allows you to make calls using COM (yum) to import, and that does full error checking (it actually calls into a running version of Quickbooks), but is probably overkill for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Quickbooks SDK](http://qbsdk.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb/0020_Get_Set_Up/SDK_Downloads) and [Documentation](http://qbsdk.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb/0050_Documentation). The SDK has two COM interface: QBFC and QBXML. The difference in using QBXML, you need to serialize and deserialize XML manually which isn't hard once you get the handle of it. And I find QBXML much more convenient since you can choose to include requests and responses you need.

Also, if you plan to use Quickbooks SDK, the [Online Reference](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) is your best friend.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Yishai. I've been using qodbc for about 10 years now and 4 or 5 different versions of quickbooks. qodbc utilizes a database-**like** syntax to interact with the company file.

**UNLIKE** any form of proper database interaction, do as little work as possible in your query itself, as the qodbc driver can take 10 seconds to 2 minutes to handle a dozen records from a table of roughly 1000 records. A process that can import 15 orders with 5 lines each means talking to customer, item, invoiceline, invoice tables and can take 5 minutes. Sadly, I often am reduced to building a MySql database based on mass exports while I sort out and understand the data. THEN I go back and try to make queries directly.

While being an ODBC data connection in windows is great, learn to distrust each link in your toolchain and figure out how to troubleshoot problems to prove aspects positively correct as well as positively wrong. My most recent problem was with QB11 on Win7 x64 computer. The php stack at the time was suspect and was causing errors. And please always try to perform error checking, which is somewhat painful in that environment, but becomes crucial when "something breaks later".

This very minute I'm researching the php stack for win7 to see if I can again trust it for use with qodbc and order importing. (exporting from magento)